# PHP Check if property exists -- always returning false

Tags: php

I have the following abstract class `Types`

```
abstract class DocumentTypes {
    const OPERATIONAL = 1; 
}
```

This relates to the values that are stored in a table. The record MUST have a type and this is passed down. So for example, if someone is entering something that is for the `OPERATIONAL` part, then this would be the type that is entered into the database.

I have a function which handles this:

```
function handle($data, $type)
{
    if(!property_exists($type, DocumentTypes::class))
    {
        throw new Exception("Property value must exist");   
    }
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is make sure that the property that is passed to `handle` is that of a property inside the abstract class `Types` the property `OPERATIONAL` exists, however, when I try to do the following:

```
$data = "asasfasfasfafs"; 

try {

    handle($data, DocumentTypes::OPERATIONAL); 

}catch(Exception $e)
{
    die($e); 
}
```

I am getting the following exception thrown:

> > First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class in

How can I therefore check that the value passed, is in actual fact a property of the `Types` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to switch the parameter order around. The class name has to come first:

```
if(!property_exists(DocumentTypes::class $type))
    ...
```

Check the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php).

Athough, the second parameter passed to `property_exists` must be a string, which is the name of the property you're looking for. So it still won't work if you're looking for `1`...

**UPDATE**
After reading some of your comments I think I understand what you're trying to do now. You want to ensure that a user is passing a valid type though, and the valid types are being defined as separate constants.

This is the way I always solve this problem:

```
abstract class DocumentTypes {
    const OPERATIONAL = 1;
    const OTHER_TYPE = 2;

    public static function validTypes()
    {
        return [
            DocumentTypes::OPERATIONAL,
            DocumentTypes::OTHER_TYPE,
        ];

    }
}
```

Then you can use the `validTypes` function to verify the `$type`:

```
public function handle($type)
{
    if (!in_array($type, DocumentTypes::validTypes(), true)) {
        throw new Exception("Property value must exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I understand where your coming from, it will always pass `1` .. is there another function that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

First, a property of a class is not the same as a constant of class.
So the function `property_exists()` do not fits you.

To check, if the type (a cosnstat exists) you have to use the `defined()` function

Secondary - I did not understand what you actually need. Do you need to check - is there a constant defined, which value that matches the input value?

If yes - Then you can't do it this way.

```
abstract class DocumentTypes {
    const OPERATIONAL = 1; 
}

// --------------

function handle($type) {
    if (!defined('DocumentTypes::' . $type)) {
        throw new Exception('Property value must exist');   
    }
}

// --------------

$data = 'asasfasfasfafs'; 
try {
    handle($data); 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, I basically want to check that if someone passes a `DocumentTypes::OPERATIONAL` then it will match up to a property inside the abstract class. If for example, someone passes through `DocumentTypes::blahblah` I want to throw an exception

Comment: Then just use `defined('DocumentTypes::blahblah');`

Comment: - That's the issue. By passing `DocumentTypes::OPERATIONAL` to the function, it gives me an integer.. So doing `defined` on this would not work as it's looking at the value and not the name

Comment: Pass it as a string, like I wrote above!